# Mircosoft Azure API $orderBy not giving the desired response

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management, azureportal, azure-service-principal

I am trying to make the following API call and I expect ordering done based on createdDateTime, however this ordering is not done by Microsoft and I am still getting response in random order, any suggestions to make it work?

GET /v1.0/servicePrincipals/{0}/appRoleAssignedTo?$orderby=createdDateTime+asc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-orderby

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, sorting is not currently supported on servicePrincipals.

[image]